# My website form inputs won't work when the screen is shrunk down to tablet/mobile view, but it works fine when maximized

Tags: javascript, html, css

My game isn't working when shrunk down to tablet view or mobile view. It works fine when it is left in a normal browser state, but for some reason it's like the website is frozen. I can't click buttons, type in numbers, or even click radio buttons.

Here is my code to shrink different layouts with different CSS:

```
<link href="styles/casino.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="styles/tablet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="handheld, only screen and (max-width:1024px), only screen and (max-device-width: 650px)">
<link href="styles/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="handheld, only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)">
<!--[if IEMobile]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles/mobile.css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
```

Here is my game form code:

```
<div id="game">
    <div id="gameScreen">
        <img src="images/roulettetable.jpg" class="desktop" height="413" width="100%" alt="Roulette Table" />
        <img src="images/roulettetable.jpg" class="tablet" height="255" width="99%" alt="Roulette Table" />
        <img src="images/roulettetable.jpg" class="phone" height="215" width="99%" alt="Roulette Table" />
        <div id="info"><p>First Name: <span id="firstN"></span><br/>Last Name: <span id="lastN"></span><br/>Phone Number: <span id="phoneN"></span><br/>Postal Code: <span id="postalC"></span><br/>Amount: <span id="startA"></span></p></div>
        <div id="cash"><p></p></div>
    </div>
    <div id="gameForm">
        <form id="gameForm">
            <label>Bet: </label>
                <input type="text" value="0" id="bet" name="betAmount" onClick="if (this.value == '0') this.value='';" required/>
            <label> 1-12: </label>
                <input type="radio" name="temp" value="1-12" id="thirdOne" onClick="deselect()"/>
            <label> 13-24: </label>
                <input type="radio" name="temp" value="13-24" id="thirdTwo" onClick="deselect()"/>
            <label> 25-36: </label>
                <input type="radio" name="temp" value="25-36" id="thirdThree" onClick="deselect()"/>
            <label>Single Number:</label>
                <input type="number" name="num" id="num" min="00" max="36" onBlur="validateNum();"/><br/><hr/>
            <label>Black:</label>
                <input type="radio" name="temp" id="blackBet" value="Black" onClick="deselect()"/>
            <label> Even: </label>
                <input type="radio" name="temp" value="even" id="evenBet" onClick="deselect()"/> 
            <label for="halfTwo"> High: </label>
                <input type="radio" name="temp" value="19-36" id="halfTwo" onClick="deselect()"/><br/>  
                <input type="button" name="spin" value="Spin!!!" id="spin" onClick="spinIt();" />   
            <label>Red:</label>
                <input type="radio" name="temp" id="redBet" value="Red" onClick="deselect()" />
            <label> Odd: </label>
                <input type="radio" name="temp" value="odd" id="oddBet" onClick="deselect()" />
            <label> Low: </label>
                <input type="radio" name="temp" value="1-18" id="halfOne" onClick="deselect()"/>
                <input type="button" name="leave" value="Leave Game" id="leave" onClick="window.location = 'outcome.html'"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```